# Javascript attachment via email

Tags: javascript, email, servicenow

I need help with a JavaScript function. I am using the ServiceNow platform.

**I have the requirements:**

- Automatically add attachments to an Incident record when sent using the email client (Works, but adds the attachment to the record twice in one update and re-adds all attachments every time)
- Track the changes in the activity log (I have this one working)
  The solutions posted in these links have gotten me close but there are issues.
  https://community.servicenow.com/thread/163398

I am using the code posted in the [Elite page here](http://www.servicenowelite.com/blog/2014/3/6/log-attachment-changes-in-activities).

**The issues:**

- A single attachment added via the email client is added to the record TWICE
- When another attachment is added later via the email client, ALL of the previous attachments are re-attached again

Why is the attachment being added to the record twice?
How can I grab just the attachments that were added in the latest update via the email client?

```
//Table: Email [sys_email]
//When: after 
//Insert: true
//Update: true
//Condition: !current.instance.nil() && current.type == 'received'
//Script:
addAttachmentAudit();
function addAttachmentAudit() {
    var instance = current.instance;
    var targetTable = current.target_table;
    var grAttachment = new GlideRecord('sys_attachment');
    grAttachment.addQuery('table_sys_id',current.sys_id);
    grAttachment.query();
    while(grAttachment.next()){
        grAttachment.table_name = targetTable;
        grAttachment.table_sys_id = instance;
        grAttachment.update();
        var grTargetTable = new GlideRecord(targetTable);
        grTargetTable.addQuery('sys_id',instance);
        grTargetTable.query();
        while (grTargetTable.next()) { 
            grTargetTable.work_notes = 
                "Attachment added: " + grAttachment.file_name + 
                " by email from " + current.sys_created_by;
            grTargetTable.update();
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered eliminating the while (grTargetTable.next()) block? Just to grTargetTable.next() manually one time, since you're querying by sys_id and thus should only have one.

I'd be interested to know if that has any effect. 
Sorry I can't comment directly on your question, I haven't enough rep yet.